# Escaping [ in Python Regular Expressions

Tags: python, regex

This reg exp search correctly checks to see if a string contains the text *harry*:

```
re.search(r'\bharry\b', '[harry] blah', re.IGNORECASE)
```

However, I need to ensure that the string contains *[harry]*. I have tried escaping with various numbers of back-slashes:

```
re.search(r'\b\[harry\]\b', '[harry] blah', re.IGNORECASE)
re.search(r'\b\\[harry\\]\b', '[harry] blah', re.IGNORECASE)
re.search(r'\b\\\[harry\\\]\b', '[harry] blah', re.IGNORECASE)
```

None of these solutions work find the match.  What do I need to do?

Comment: '[harry]' in '[harry] blah'.lower() --> shorter, faster, and easier to read.

Comment: @Wang: Shorter and easier to read, but not necessarily faster, because of the `.lower()` method call. Try comparing the two methods with an input string of `"blah [harry] blah" + " more data"*1000`

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The first one is correct:

```
r'\b\[harry\]\b'
```

But this won’t match `[harry] blah` as `[` is not a word character and so there is no word boundary. It would only match if there were a word character in front of `[` like in `foobar[harry] blah`.

Comment: To match the exact example (`'[harry] blah`) you need an additional space like this `r'\b\[harry\] \b'`.

Answer (score 2):

You escape it the way you escape most regex metacharacter: preceding with a backslash.

Thus, `r"\[harry\]"` will match a literal string `[harry]`.

The problem is with the `\b` in your pattern. This is the *word boundary anchor*.

The `\b` matches:

- At the beginning of the string, if it starts with a word character
- At the end of the string, if it ends with a word character
- Between a word character `\w` and a non-word character `\W` (note the case difference)

The brackets `[` and `]` are NOT word characters, thus if a string starts with `[`, there is no `\b` to its left. Any where there is no `\b`, there is `\B` instead (note the case difference).

#### References

- [regular-expressions.info/Word Boundaries](http://www.regular-expressions.info/wordboundaries.html)
- http://docs.python.org/library/re.html

  > `\b` : Matches the empty string, but only at the beginning or end of a word. A word is defined as a sequence of alphanumeric or underscore characters, so the end of a word is indicated by whitespace or a non-alphanumeric, non-underscore character. Note that `\b` is defined as the boundary between `\w` and `\W`, so the precise set of characters deemed to be alphanumeric depends on the values of the UNICODE and LOCALE flags. Inside a character range, `\b` represents the backspace character, for compatibility with Python’s string literals.

Comment: See with example when `\b\[harry\]\b` can match: http://www.rubular.com/r/29VeekGwuD

Answer (score 2):

```
>>> re.search(r'\bharry\b','[harry] blah',re.IGNORECASE)
<_sre.SRE_Match object at 0x7f14d22df648>
>>> re.search(r'\b\[harry\]\b','[harry] blah',re.IGNORECASE)
>>> re.search(r'\[harry\]','[harry] blah',re.IGNORECASE)
<_sre.SRE_Match object at 0x7f14d22df6b0>
>>> re.search(r'\[harry\]','harry blah',re.IGNORECASE)
```

The problem is the `\b`, not the brackets. A single backslash is correct for escaping.